# Python dataframe remove substring before specific character if ture

Tags: python, dataframe, substring, strip

I am trying to remove the numbers before "-" in the name column. But not all rows have numbers before the name. How do I remove the numbers in rows that have numbers and keep the rows that don't have numbers in front untouched?

Sample df:

```
country     Name
UK          5413-Marcus
Russia      5841-Natasha
Hong Kong   Keith
China       7777-Wang
```

Desired df

```
country     Name
UK          Marcus
Russia      Natasha
Hong Kong   Keith
China       Wang
```

I appreciate any assistance! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Pandas has string accessors for series. If you split and get the last element of the resulting list, even if a row does not have the delimeter '-' you still want the last element of that one-element list.

```
df.Name = df.Name.str.split('-').str.get(-1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just tried it but it gave me an error: KeyError: -1

Comment: Thanks for the edit. This answer works now. Really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 1):

You might use `str.lstrip` for that task following way:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'country':['UK','Russia','Hong Kong','China'],'Name':['5413-Marcus','5841-Natasha','Keith','7777-Wang']})
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.lstrip('-0123456789')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     country     Name
0         UK   Marcus
1     Russia  Natasha
2  Hong Kong    Keith
3      China     Wang
```

`.lstrip` does remove leading characters, `.rstrip` trailing characters and `.strip` both.